# RegEX for finding a random lowercase alphanumeric string bounded from right

Tags: regex, dart

I'm trying to create a simple application that will open and read a file, then will change the value of a property using dart. I've opened the file and then read, and I changed a value of a text and then saved, it worked. But, the thing is that I want to find this text in the file:

```
final String url = '080d3f60.ngrok.io';
```

But the value of the url can change, I'm trying to create a regex to find the string and then replace it with the new value.

Is it possible to create a regex that does this?

The ngrok URL is created randomly, but it always have the `.ngrok.io` in the end.

Comment: Do you need the whole line or just the string? Have you tried a regex?

Comment: I need only the string to replace it, I've tried but it didn't work, i don't know regex very well yet

Comment: @Emma's answer is good enough but if the string occurs somewhere else in the file you may find duplicates. Use this if you only want to change on this line `(?:final\s*String\s*url\s*\=\s*\')(\w+\.ngrok\.io)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/B1gq2L/2) might help you to do so:

```
 [a-z0-9]+.ngrok.io
```

We can simply add additional boundaries, if you wish.

[image]

#### Group

We can also use capturing group `()` and target the random string, if you wish, similar to [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/9BmGQl/1), where the group can be simply called using `$1`:

```
([a-z0-9]+).ngrok.io
```

[image: RegEx]

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52615539/dartfind-and-replace-strings) might also help you to do find/replace.